# Using Quickdeply from metadata API

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, metadata

Do I need to pass any special parameters when I use Quickdeploy using metadata api ? Or should I just use the validate option and it sends the info to the org for Quickdeploy? How does ANT know when it has to send the code for validation or send the code for Quickdeploy?

Answer (score 0):

There is one new tag

```
<sf:deployRecentValidation>
```

which is used to do quick deploy. You need to pass the recent validated deployment id which was validated recently as follows

```
<target name="quickDeploy">
  <sf:deployRecentValidation  username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}"
 sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" 
recentValidationId="${sf.recentValidationId}"/>
</target>
```

Ref article: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool_deploy_validation.htm